Preview is missing environmentobject object "DataController"?
I have a weird error where my preview provider is crashing because "Preview is missing environment object "DataController" in a particular view. However, it works in a different view and I am not able to understand why it works in one but not the other.
Upon regular app launch, the app.swift will be the root level to pass the environment objects down:
@available(iOS 17, *)
@main
struct TestApp: App {

    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController.shared
    @StateObject private var globalSettings = GlobalSettings()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if dataController.isUserLoggedIn {
                MainPageView(
                   searchPageViewModel: SearchPageViewModel(),
                   profilePageViewModel: ProfilePageViewModel(context: 
                       MockDataController.shared.context),
                   postPreViewModel: PostPrePageViewModel()
                )
                .environment(\.modelContext, dataController.context)
                .environmentObject(globalSettings)
                .environmentObject(dataController)
            } else {
                LoginPageView()
                    .environment(\.modelContext, dataController.context)
                    .environmentObject(globalSettings)
                    .environmentObject(dataController)
            }
        }
    }
}

However, in specific view previews, I must inject the environmentObjects explicitly. This works perfectly fine in this view:
import SwiftUI

class GlobalSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPostBegun = false
}

@available(iOS 17, *)
struct MainPageView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globalSettings: GlobalSettings
    @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController

    @ObservedObject var searchPageViewModel: SearchPageViewModel
    @ObservedObject var profilePageViewModel: ProfilePageViewModel
    @ObservedObject var postPreViewModel: PostPrePageViewModel

    @State private var selectedTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()

            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                FeedPageView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                    }
                    .tag(0)

                SearchPageView(viewModel: searchPageViewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                    }
                    .tag(1)

                PostPrePageView(viewModel: postPreViewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    }
                    .tag(2)

                ActivityPageView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "bolt")
                    }
                    .tag(3)

                ProfilePageView(profilePageViewModel: profilePageViewModel)
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                    }
                    .tag(4)
            }
            .toolbarBackground(.black, for: .tabBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .tabBar)
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

@available(iOS 17, *)
struct MainPageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainPageView(
            searchPageViewModel: SearchPageViewModel(),
            profilePageViewModel: ProfilePageViewModel(context: MockDataController.shared.context),
            postPreViewModel: PostPrePageViewModel()
        )
        .environmentObject(GlobalSettings())
        .environmentObject(MockDataController.shared)
    }
}
 

This works with no problems.
However, the other potential user landing page from the app launch, LoginPage, yields the error "Preview is missing environment object "DataController".
import SwiftUI
import AWSMobileClientXCF
import AWSCognitoIdentityProvider
import UIKit
import KeychainAccess


struct RoundedTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 16, bottom: 8, trailing: 16))
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
            )
    }
}

    @available(iOS 17, *)
    struct LoginPageView: View {
        @State private var emailInput: String = ""
        @State private var passwordInput: String = ""
        @State private var isUserAuthenticated: Bool = false
        
    
        @EnvironmentObject var globalSettings: GlobalSettings
        @EnvironmentObject var dataController: DataController
    
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                ZStack {
                    Color(.black)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Label("Label", systemImage: "42.circle")
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Image("Prelim Icon")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        TextField("Email", text: $emailInput)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedTextFieldStyle())
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8)
                        
                        TextField("Password", text: $passwordInput)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedTextFieldStyle())
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8)
                        
                        Spacer().frame(height: 20)
                        
                        Button("Login") {
                            LoginButtonPressed()
                        }
                    
                        NavigationLink(destination: SignUpPageView()) {
                            Text("Sign Up")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isUserAuthenticated) {
                        MainPageView(
                            searchPageViewModel: SearchPageViewModel(),
                            profilePageViewModel: ProfilePageViewModel(context: dataController.context),
                            postPreViewModel: PostPrePageViewModel()
                        )
                    }
                        
    
                }
            }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
        
        func LoginButtonPressed() {
            // Simulate authentication logic
            if emailInput == "test@example.com" && passwordInput == "password" {
                isUserAuthenticated = true
            } else {
                print("Invalid credentials")
            }
        }
    }
    
    @available(iOS 17, *)
    struct LoginPage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            LoginPageView()
                .environmentObject(GlobalSettings())
                .environmentObject(MockDataController.shared)
        }
    }

I just don't understand why MainPageView doesn't have this error, but LoginPageView does, despite the enivronmentObjects being set up in the same way? What am I missing here? I considered that perhaps using MockDataController instead of DataController may cause the issue, but both previews are using this and only one shows the error.
To be thorough I checked a few other stack questions here, here, and here and none of them solved my problem.
Edit: I can remove the error by manually passing the value into the MainPageView initiation in the NavigationLink as follows:
.navigationDestination(isPresented: $isUserAuthenticated) {
   MainPageView(
      searchPageViewModel: SearchPageViewModel(),
      profilePageViewModel: ProfilePageViewModel(context: Mockdatacontroller.shared.context),
      postPreViewModel: PostPrePageViewModel()
   )
}

Hopefully this helps explain what is happening?
This is just less ideal because I'm hard coding which datacontroller to use (MockDataController for previews and DataController in actual app) rather than allowing it to seamlessly make the switch depending which I am using via the @EnvironmentObject.
Its also in theory not exactly a problem cause the actual app works fine and doesn't throw an error, but its just annoying that I don't understand what is happening.

Is it because MainPageView has the ProfilePageViewModel observed object and LoginPageView doesn't?

But my intention is to not load any of the view viewmodels unless the user is already logged in or successfully authenticates... why load them at the login screen? MainPage needs to house these objects with these vars because they will be passed from the app open conditional. If just at login screen, successful authentication will prompt loading of now needed viewmodels on the spot, hence not needing it to hold a passed value from the app launch. Or am I wrong?

I don’t get it why you have to load your viewmodels from the TestApp.

Why does DataController even need to be an EnvironmentObjet when it is a shared type? You can already access it everywhere anyway using DataController.shared.

@LawrenceGimenez I don't really understand. Why wouldn't the app.swift be the place to load the viewmodels? It dictates what page opens when the user opens the app right? That seems like a good time to load the viewmodels?

@JoakimDanielson I did not know this. Wouldn't I be losing the immediate-updating of the UI that comes from using the environmentObject since it integrates natively with SwiftUI? I guess I could take this off to remove the error but ideally this would be in place.

I mean for SearchPageViewModel(), only MainPageView uses this. Why not instantiate this inside MainPageView with @StateObject so you don't have to add it as parameter.

I don't understand the benefit. With my approach, all viewmodels are loaded at app open and passing it as a parameter makes it clear what needs what. What do I achieve by not needing to add it as a parameter?
